# Simple WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, wysiwyg

Im searching for a real simple WYSIWYG Editor to embed it in a RoR Application. The trouble is that it should be used by 0815 users that dont want to learn a markup language. I know most WYSIWYG editors prduce bad HTML but there is no alternative for this project.

What I need is a real basic editor that provides the possibility to use headlines, lists, images and breaks (`<p>`). There is no need to set the fonts, sizes,... this should be set by my css.

I already tryed tinyMCE but its a mess in this case because its overloaded with functions that I dont need. I know I can turn them off but Im searching for a slim alternative that produces clean html!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Choose your poison.](http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors)

Comment: Thank you I think Ill give jWYSIWYG a try!